# WP7 - Navigaton stops working after the application is deactivated and reactivated

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have recently upgraded the app from WP7 7.0 to 7.1. Now every time the application gets deactivated and reactivated (I press the Home button and then the back button) the navigation will stop working completely. The NavigationService will return "true" and not throw any exceptions, while the navigation will simply be ignored, thus breaking the application.

I don't know what is causing the problem. RootFrame_NavigationFailed also doesn't catch anything, and the event is simply ignored.

Comment: Posting some code might help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade directly to 7.1 or created a new project